# NextGEN Gallery styles don't work

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am new to wordpress but I'm ambitious and I'm diving right into theme creation from scratch. So far so good until now...

I've installed the nextGEN gallery but the styles wont work (i.e. Hovereffect styles).  Everything works except the images just show in a plain column.  If I add  to the header.php the styles work but my header image gets messed up.

What would be the proper way to code my theme to work with the styles of this plugin?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I found the answer (or at least this worked)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answerto my own question.  Hooray!  Don't know if it's completely proper but this worked.

I added the code:   to the footer.php and voila!

[This is the tutorial that helped me](http://mediaformations.com/nextgen-gallery-effects-not-working/)